# Проблема запуска Ubuntu на Xorg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, wayland

Проблема такая: на Ubuntu 22.04  не работают приложения записывающие скринкасты, нет звука. В итоге начитался в интернете что при запуске через Xorg все заработает. Но при попытке запуститься через Xorg получаю темный экран
Мои действия: выход из аккаунта, при запуске окна регистрации в нижнем углу нажимаю на шестеренки и  меняю Ubuntu->Ubuntu on Xorg.
Итог: получаю черный экран, местами красно-черные пятна и какие то куски изображения проглядываются в верхнем углу, но в целом ничего невозможно разобрать

Comment: Может быть графический режим по-умолчанию выставлен неверный, может быть драйвера кривые. Но в любом случае я не улавливаю связь между звуком и графической подсистемой. Проверьте звуковые устройства, попробуйте пошаманить с настройками https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423121/no-sound-in-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-after-upgrading-from-20-04-lts

Comment: @PakUula может быть связанно с порталами